# Add attributes to Current Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How to I could set '`attributes`' to current `Thread` in Java, I want to set key-values and get the value in another place, but in the same Thread. like to this http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not think you can add attributes to any given thread in Java, but you could use a `ThreadLocal` instance to store any special information per thread.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: This is exactly how it is done in log4j MDC, and also EJB transaction context and security context is carried along the same way during a request -- this is one of the reasons EJB prohibits from starting own threads.

Answer (score 7):

Here's sample code for @edalorzo's answer:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ThreadAttributes {
    private static ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> threadAttrs = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> initialValue() {
            return new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    };

    public static String get(String key) {
        return threadAttrs.get().get(key);
    }

    public static void set(String key, String value) {
        threadAttrs.get().put(key, value);
    }
}
```

To use it just this:

```
ThreadAttributes.get("attribute"); //to get an attribute
ThreadAttributes.set("attribute", "toValue"); //to set an attribute
```

Warning: if you application creates lots threads and does not reuse them this code will potentially leak `HashMap`s.

Comment: On the other hand ThreadLocal variables tend to have problems with thread pools, since when a tread from the pool is re-used it will be assigned the same thread local variable as the last time it was in use. Therefore, it is important to check this is not an issue.

Comment: That's very true. I guess it really depends on what is the requirement. If you need attributes that are task-scoped (`Runnable#run()`-scoped, for instance) it might be worth looking at source code for Google Guice framework, which allowes you to scope instances.